# Compare structs and arrays with keccak256 in order to save gas

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, hash, keccak

Just working on a solidity code last day, I figured out that apart of comparing bytes, strings etc...

The `Keccak256` will be the perfect solution for comparing large arrays or big structs. Because as the Hash functions properties say:

> Given **x and y with the assumption (x != y)** => We can assume that **H(x) != H(y)**

So **comparing it's hashes will make us spend a lot less Gas than iterating the array, and demonstrate us that they are or no equal** (doesn't matter on which index).

So with an example:

Let's supose that we have 2 large arrays of the same type. Will it be possible to do something as:

```
Assert.equal(keccak256(array1)), keccak256(array2));
```

**That is what you do in order to compare strings for example**. (That if I'm not wrong, are interpreted as arrays at the end).

In order to don't do something like:

```
Assert.equal(array1[i], array2[i]); 
//Implemented on a for loop from i=0 to i=minlength(arr1,arr2)
```

Obviously, other implementations as adding mappings or stuff like that can solve quite well the problem, but **I'm interested on knowing if there's any trick that allows you to compare this types of stuctures with the `keccak256()`**.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this should be phrased as a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is!

As `keccak256` in Solidity yieds a `bytes32` value, you could just compare the outcomes using `==`.

An example:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract KeccakCompare {
    struct Example {
        uint256 age;
        bytes32 name;
    }

    Example[] public examples;

    function pushExample(uint256 _age, bytes32 _name) external {
        examples.push(Example({
            age: _age,
            name: _name
        }));
    }

    function equals(uint256 _firstIndex, uint256 _secondIndex) external view returns (bool) {
        return equals(examples[_firstIndex], examples[_secondIndex]);
    }

    function equals(Example storage _first, Example storage _second) internal view returns (bool) {
        // Just compare the output of hashing all fields packed
        return(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_first.age, _first.name)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_second.age, _second.name)));
    }
}
```

Comment: A very nice explanation by demonstrating the 2 statements on the same code. Thank you so much and good job!

Comment: It's not true that hashing any value costs 30 gas. It's 30 gas + 6*array.length